# Qt and OpenGL and draw a triangle if i use attributes

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a problem with a simple shader.
I plan to draw a triangle (one for a start) in color. What i want: i culculete color for each node of triangle and give it to vertex shader, then pass to fragmant and get a colorfull triangle. What i get is nothing - no triangle. So i decided to simplify a littel - i give parameters to shaders, but i not use them. And i get same result. It's C++ code:

```
    QVector4D colors[3];
     ...       
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        invers_sh.setAttributeValue("b_color", colors[1]);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);

        invers_sh.setAttributeValue("b_color", colors[1]);
        glVertex2d(2.0, 0);

        invers_sh.setAttributeValue("b_color", colors[2]);
        glVertex2d(0, 2.0);


    glEnd();
```

Vertex shader:

```
in vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 b_color;
varying vec4 color_v;
uniform mat4 qt_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = qt_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex;
    color_v = b_color;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 color_v;

void main( void )
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I figured that i get my red triangle if i comment all setAttributeValue in C++ code and line

```
color_v = b_color;
```

in vertex shader.
Help me.

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?  Why are you trying to use `in` ***and*** `attribute`?

Comment: I just modified example, that i found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test the following `invers_sh.setAttributeValue("b_color", colors[0]);`

=> replace that line with

```
invers_sh.setAttributeValue(b_colorLocation, colors[1]);
```

set a global for colorLocation

```
int b_colorLocation;
```

and add this to where you compile your shaders get location of b_color:

```
b_colorLocation = invers_sh.attributeLocation("b_color");
```

Comment: Same thing. If color_v = b_color; is in shader it's doesn't work.

Comment: well that was once solved my problem, can you try adding the following: invers_sh.enableAttributeArray ( "b_color"); before glBegin and invers_sh.disableAttributeArray ( "b_color"); after glEnd

Comment: Oh, i found it: i checked value of 'b_colorLocation' and it's 0. So in vertex shader i wrote 'layout(location = 2) in vec4 b_color;' and now all working! Thank you!